# After Purpule screen Balck Screen insted of login screen on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login, login-screen

I am new to the linux ,I did a few changes and next time when i tried to login i see black screen it stays there.

After selecting ubuntu option from GRUB ,I can see purple screen for a while then black screen with some log messages the last message is **Started Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data**.

**Before this problem i did following changes:**

**1**.Uninstalled **Terminator,arduino,git tree gui client**  packages from Ubuntu software center and by command "sudo apt-get remove /purge  package_name"

**2**.last time Force Shut down while some processes were running

**3**.Also I have around only 3-4 GB space left

I think removing packages caused issue ,But not sure.

**I am able to logging to my account through"ctrl+alt+f1"**

I have dualboot system ,but it was working fine from last 4 months.

What could be the problem ?

**Attempts:**

1.Tried this command from tty1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity

2. Tried
   sudo lightdm 
   but again no login screen bt the black screen with some messages
   the last message is "[OK] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch. Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status..."

Comment: What are the 'few changes' that you made?

Comment: you indicated you used commands to make changes; the command `history` will show your command-history (to tell us what you removed)

Comment: @PalKerecsenyi  I removed some packages(Terminator,arduino,git tree gui client...  ) using" purge" and "sudo apt-get remove"

Comment: If you want help, do not withhold information. Edit your question and list exactly the packages you removed. Saying "some packages" is useless.

Comment: Sorry , Edited the changes and updated question

Comment: @KrishnaKatore what graphics card do you have? can you browse the grub menu ?

Comment: @papajo I have Intel Sky Lake integrated graphics, And Yes I can Browse the Grub menu

Comment: I suspect that your system could have been recoverable before you did "2" installing unity again etc... It seems to me that there is a mess only advanced users could solve and even those might need to have the computer infront of them to make sense of it... What I suggest you to do is to update using a usb for a newer version of ubuntu during the installation it will ask you if you want to upgrade without losing your files if you click that option you gonna have a brand new OS with all your settings and files intact. Thats the easiest way I think to solve this mess.

Comment: @papajo i tried to installed unity ,But as it was already installed so i got the message as "Unity is already the newest version(7.4.0+16.04.20160906-0ubuntu1)"

Comment: @OrganicMarble you have any solution for this?

Comment: No I dont mean to install unity using the terminal, I mean download and make a bootable ubuntu installation disc or usb of a newer version (e.g 17.04 or 17.10 or atleast 16.10) and  boot with that (live cd/usb) then from inside it install ubuntu at some point it will give you the option to UPGRADE ubuntu WITHOUT losing your files(it has to say that or else its not the right option) by doing that you will fix your issue without needing to do advanced IT stuff... Thats what I think you should do.

Comment: @papajo UPGRADING ubuntu will it keep all my installed packages as is with new UBUNTU?  also will it keep my all data that i have ?Since after lots of configurations and installation packages i am able to set build environment for android open source development

Comment: yes it will IF you get the upgrade option that clearly says that you will keep your files . I dont remember how exactly it will look like but the option MUST have the words UPGRADE and clearly say underneath that you WONT LOSE your files.  otherwise it means that the installation cd for some reason can not recognize any existing ubuntu version on the hard drive and will promt you to format the disk or something. but check if the version is compatible with the packets you want to keep they wont get deleted but they may not work with the upgraded version.

Comment: The probable solution is to re install Ubuntu entirely, making a backup of your docs first.